# How do I count categorical values from a dataset and transform the summation into a new dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-structures, data-analysis

I have a dataset that tracks categorical (Yes/No) responses to a questionnaire formatted like this:

| Client_Id | Question_1 | Question_2 | Question_3 | Question_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | No | No | Yes | Yes |
| 1001 | Yes | Yes | Yes | No |
| 1002 | No | Yes | Yes | Yes |

I'm trying to count the number of Y or N responses to each question and transform them into a dataset formatted like this:

| Response | Question_1 | Question_2 | Question_3 | Question_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yes | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2 |
| No | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

I've successfully counted the responses with this for loop:

for c in test_df.columns:
d = test_df[c].value_counts().reindex(['Yes','No'], fill_value=0)
print(d)

Now I just want to put the information into a new dataset.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option using [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) (only if you have a binary value like Yes/No):

```
m = df.filter(like='Question').eq('Yes').sum()

out = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Yes': m, 'No': len(df)-m}, orient='index')
```

Or a more generic approach with [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
out = (df.filter(like='Question')
         .melt().value_counts()
         .unstack('variable', fill_value=0)
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
      )
```

Or [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
s = df.filter(like='Question').stack()

out = (pd.crosstab(s, s.index.get_level_values(1))
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
       )
```

Output:

```
     Question_1   Question_2   Question_3   Question_4
Yes            1            2            3           2
No             2            1            0           1
```